# How do I build this simple example with Bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel

Suppose I have a project like this:

```sh
$ tree . 
├── WORKSPACE
├── include
│   └── header.hpp
└── main.cpp
└── BUILD.bazel
```

And `main.cpp` looks like this:

```cpp
#include "header.hpp"

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

What should my `BUILD.bazel` file look like?

My current attempt:

```py
cc_binary(
  name = "app",
  srcs = [
    "main.cpp",
    "include/header.hpp",
  ],
)
```

---

Edit: Forgot to mention my `WORKSPACE` file

---

Edit: Found a work-around, but I don't think it is very elegant:

```py
cc_library(
  name = "app-hdrs",
  hdrs = [
    "include/header.hpp",
  ],
  srcs = [
    "include/header.hpp",
  ],
  strip_include_prefix = "include",
)

cc_binary(
  name = "app",
  srcs = [
    "main.cpp",
  ],
  deps = [
    ":app-hdrs",
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a file called `WORKSPACE` in your project folder:

```sh
$ tree . 
├── include
│   └── header.hpp
└── main.cpp
└── BUILD.bazel
└── WORKSPACE
```

Then you can build your app with the following commmand:

`bazel build //:app`

And also specify the include path in the `copts`-flag:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "app",
  srcs = [
    "main.cpp",
    "include/header.hpp",
  ],
  copts = ["-Iinclude", "-Wall", "-Werror"],
)
```

---

```
cc_binary(
  name = "app",
  includes = [ "include" ],
  srcs = [
    "main.cpp",
    "include/header.hpp",
  ],
  copts = [ "-Wall", "-Werror" ],
)
```

Comment: `-Iinclude` is quite manual and not cross-platform. Is there not a better way?

Comment: @sdgfsdh you can specify the [`includes`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary)-flag in your `cc_binary`, but not sure there is any difference:  `includes = ["include_dir"]`

Comment: `-I` is a GCC flag so if I use this it will not work with MSVC. I would prefer Bazel to generate such flags depending on the platform / toolchain

Comment: @sdgfsdh have you tried the `includes`-flag? According to the docs it ust prepends `-isystem` but maybe it prepends something different for MSVC. If it doesn't work, I guess you will need to write [configs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1712) (more info [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select)) for the different compiler